# Compile all tex files in a directory

Tags: bash, latex

If I do `pdflatex *.tex` in a directory, only one `tex` file is compiled. Which syntax should I use that all `*.tex` files in the directory are compiled?

Comment: Btw, [`tex.stackexchange.com` has a valuable thread on "*tools for automating document compilation*"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
for file in *.tex; do pdflatex "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 6):

`pdflatex` apparently only takes one argument. I can think of using `find -exec`

```
find -name '*.tex' -maxdepth 1 -exec pdflatex {} \;
```

But there may be better alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Less typing, if no spaces in files:

```
 echo *.tex|xargs -n1 pdflatex
```