# echo all *.tex filenames in a specific directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

I have a directory structure like this:

```
├── lebenslauf
│   ├── lebenslauf.out
│   └── lebenslauf.tex
├── thirdPage
│   ├── auto
│   │   ├── test.el
│   │   └── thirdPage.el
│   ├── missfont.log
│   ├── thirdPage.aux
│   ├── thirdPage.log
│   ├── thirdPage.pdf
│   └── thirdPage.tex
└── titlePage
    ├── titlePage.aux
    ├── titlePage.fdb_latexmk
    ├── titlePage.fls
    ├── titlePage.log
    ├── titlePage.pdf
    ├── titlePage.tex
    └── titlePage.tex~
```

I want to perform some actions on `titlePage.tex` and `lebenslauf.tex`. For that purpose, I want to print out the relative path of its location:

desired result:

```
$ ./script
lebenslauf/lebenslauf.tex
titlePage/titlePage.tex
```

That means, I want to have the path `thirdPage/` completely ignored. Therefore, I think [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37683/compile-all-tex-files-in-a-directory) isn't helpful for my purposes. Additionally, I'm curious what causes the problem in my script, so I don't want to have a solution using e.g. find.

I have written the following script for that purpose:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
IFS=$'\n\t'
set -euo pipefail

d=( lebenslauf titlePage )
for file in "./${d[@]}"
do
    if [[  $file =~ *.tex  ]]
    then
        echo $file
    fi
done
```

Which prints out just nothing. I fiddled with some variants of that, but nothing works. This is in my opinion the "best" result of what I achieved so far.

Comment: If your input is just those two filenames you could replace it all with `echo */titlePage.tex */lebenslauf.tex` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Well, i used "echo" just for the purpose to remove unneccessary complexity of the script. So no, i could not use your suggestion, as there is a lot more involved (= about 50 lines of code) than that simple operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*.tex` is a pattern, not a regular expression. To match against a pattern, don't use the `=~` operator.

Also, your loop iterates over the directories, not the files inside them.

```
d=( lebenslauf titlePage )
for dir in "${d[@]}" ; do
    for file in "$dir"/*.tex ; do
        echo $file
    done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to act on the each directory as a whole, you can make a single loop to enumerate all the files. Activate the ksh-style [extended patterns](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) to get or-patterns.

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in @(lebenslauf|titlePage)/*.tex; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

N.B. [Always use double quotes around variable substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

Answer (score -1):

much simpler would be probably:

```
ls */file1.tex */file2.tex
```

or

```
ls */*.tex | egrep '/(file1|file2).tex'
```

or

```
ls */*.tex | grep -v 'thirdPage/'
```

depending on how much you wish to type...

Comment: Well, for my purposes this is actually more complicated, because I want to execute approximately 50 sed commands on it and run xelatex on it afterwards.

Comment: ls [lt]*/*.tex | xargs sed -i 's/1/2/g'

Comment: With some knowledge of shell, it's often easy to do very powerful things typing just few keys. in cases there others require sophisticated scripts. I would say that you only need to write a script if you really want to do something repeatedly later. Otherwise shell history is much simpler and faster.

Comment: this was a part of a script :)